# iOS Webview with sharing method

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS Webview application what I need is the following 
1. inside the Webview there is a button share application and on this button click I want to let the app to share  "check this out with the url link of the app in the store",

how ever i know this is possible but in the html code this button is set like href "sha" and then the button information.
 now for me to be able to make this request work I need to set the app to detect the first 4 words take it out and open the share sheet
like this

- get url
- check 1st 4 chars = “sha:”
- if true, open in safari
- if false, open in webview
- and then open share and share the app

how do I do this? if any1 can help me by doing this please.

thank you in advance

a quick example i did a similar coding type with the opening of a url outside of the Webview.

1. the html button code :
   href="out:http://www.mini-zambesiauto.co.za/contact.html">MINI Legends @ Zambesi

there after to do the 4steps I needed to code as follow

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
URLString = [URLString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

if ([[URLString substringToIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"out:"]) {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        NSString *savedURL = [URLString substringFromIndex:4];
        NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:savedURL];
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [application openURL:finalURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

if I implement this method it works by opening external links outside the Webview.

now as seen on top I need the same method to implement into the share application but instead of opening a website it must share the application link for example in a native app looks as follow 
iOS native share application:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome app for aspiring iOS Developers!";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.exampleapp.com/"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: ok will do ill edit the question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to reformulate your question after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: or if there is any other way for the to read the link and share the app content only problem is I don't have access to the website.